# facing windows script host error whenever i create and start a .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

This `error` is showing for me whenever I create a new `.js` file example: `teams.js`

this is the error that appears :

> `Script: C:\**\**\Desktop\foot\teams.js Line: 1 Charact : 1 Error: Syntax error Code: 800A03EA Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error` 
> [image: JScript Eror]

Everything was normal and working perfectly.

As usual, I turned off my pc and the error appeared the next day.

On the first day, the error was saying that **windows do not have the appropriate authorization for accessing file /path **

[image: Spanish]

I looked for it on the internet, and I found a solution that says to uninstall adobe Flashplayer and reinstall it, I did so but the error remains.

Comment: How do you run this file?

Comment: Re Flash: ["Companies reliant on Flash for development and playback of content are encouraged to remove the dependency on Adobe Flash prior to December 2020."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/adobe-flash-end-of-support)